# Reuse RecyclerView method onBindViewHolder in pop up menu

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I nee to get current recyclerview item position when i press on pop up menu but i fail to do it , please help me.

```
    holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //creating a popup menu
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mCtx, holder.buttonViewOption);
            //inflating menu from xml resource
            popup.inflate(R.menu.options_menu);
            //adding click listener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.menu1:

                            MyLis item =list.get(onBindViewHolder(getItemViewType(position)));                     
               Intent i = new Intent(mCtx, NewClass.class);
             i.putExtra("name",item .getName());
              mContext.startActivity(i);

                            break;
                        case R.id.menu2:
                            //handle menu2 click
                            break;
                        case R.id.menu3:
                            //handle menu3 click
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            //displaying the popup
            popup.show();

        }
    });
```

*Entire code is* **CustomAdapter.java**  :

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<MyList> list;
private Context mCtx;

public CustomAdapter(List<MyList> list, Context mCtx) {
    this.list = list;
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MyList myList = list.get(position);
    holder.textViewHead.setText(myList.getHead());
    holder.textViewDesc.setText(myList.getDesc());

    holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //creating a popup menu
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mCtx, holder.buttonViewOption);
            //inflating menu from xml resource
            popup.inflate(R.menu.options_menu);
            //adding click listener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.menu1:

                            MyLis item =list.get(onBindViewHolder(getItemViewType(position)));                     
               Intent i = new Intent(mCtx, NewClass.class);
             i.putExtra("name",item .getName());
              mContext.startActivity(i);

                            break;
                        case R.id.menu2:
                            //handle menu2 click
                            break;
                        case R.id.menu3:
                            //handle menu3 click
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            //displaying the popup
            popup.show();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: MyList item =list.get(position); have you tried this?

Comment: @Rajesh yes , `positon`  will mark an error 'cause is not defined in this pop up menu method  but in onBindViewHolder method

Comment: implement `View.OnClickListener` in your `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` (class Foo extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListene {...)

Comment: please put log you have get while using `position`

Comment: Get position on holder button click (get layout position) and use this position in your popupmenu to get item in list(list.get(position)) that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just replace this

```
case R.id.menu1:
     Intent i = new Intent(mCtx, NewClass.class);
     i.putExtra("name", myList.getName());
     mContext.startActivity(i);
     break;
```

you not need `MyLis item =list.get(onBindViewHolder(getItemViewType(position)));` anymore when you have decalre this `MyList myList = list.get(position);` top in BindViewHoldee

Comment: Thanks my Man @Rajesh, It worked . I hope if we meet i can buy one bottle of beer for you . hhhh cheers

Comment: @user3518835 Happy Coding :)